# How to start GNN optimization to get higher precision?

Tags: binary-data, roc, precision-recall, graph-theory, curves

I'm developing a GNN for missing links prediction following this [blog post](https://github.com/pyg-team/pytorch_geometric/discussions/7264) for PyG library. I'm using almost the same GNN with a different dataset. Altough my dataset is similar to the MovieLens example (a bi-partite graph with some links and some missing links, with different features), I want to develop a more precise predictor rather than a recommender (at least a more precise recommender).

The following ROC and PR curves represent my current results:

[image: ROC curve]

[image: PR curve]

From my newbie evaluation on binary classification tasks (since the missing links problem is somehow generalized to a binary classification), I need to improve my precision. Is it right?

If so, where should I start? Changing my GNN model or changing the dataset trying to include more positive samples during the training?

Basically, (I think) I know what I want, which is a higher precision, with more true positives and fewer false positives. However, I don't know how to start this optimization. Is there any technique or metric I should use to get a better tip?